# Prevent saving of custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

My question is rather simple. How can I stop a custom post type from getting save in the database?

I'm specifically trying to prevent ACF field configurations from being saved on production as they should be exclusively load from JSON files.

Comment: [read the ACF documentation here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/local-json/#loading-explained)

Comment: You can add `define('ACF_LITE', true);` to your `wp-config.php` to stop the ACF plugin from registering it's user interface (which will prevent your clients from saving ACF field configurations) but will still run normally with any fields registered via PHP or JSON configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the infos. We already did most of that but there was a corner case that I wanted to prevent by preventing even ourselves from saving configurations on the production site. It's probably safer though to simply disable the user interface on production without any exceptions.